# Rectangles changing after each drawing

Tags: java, swing

So I'm trying to create a program where the user can draw shapes on a JPanel. But I've had issues with displaying the shapes in order. I've come up with a poor way of displaying the shapes (just rectangles for now) from first to last: placing each rectangle in a `Set`, and then storing an integer in a `List` that determines the color of the rectangle and whether it is filled in or not. For instance, consider the list below:

2 - Red rectangle, open

3 - Red rectangle, filled

7 - Orange rectangle, open

8 - Orange rectangle, filled

...

42 - Black rectangle, open

43 - Black rectangle, filled

So if the user were to draw a black rectangle that was open, the program would store the number 42 in the `List`, and then when the program goes back to draw each rectangle, it'll look up the number that corresponds with the rectangle, setting the color and drawing or filling the rectangle.

But there is a complication with this: Say, for example, I draw a few red rectangles, and then switch to drawing  orange rectangles. Sometimes when I finish drawing an orange rectangle, one of the rectangles that I drew previously will turn orange, despite the corresponding integer in the list pointing otherwise. I know that this is probably stemming from my terrible attempt of drawing all the rectangles in order, but I can't think of any other ways of doing so.

Is the fact that the rectangles are changing color stemming from another one of the things about painting that I can't control? Is there a better way for me to store and repaint the shapes in order?

```
public class GraphicsTest {
    public GraphicsTest() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        Painter painter = new Painter();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setJMenuBar(painter.createMenuBar());
        frame.add(painter,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(750,488);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GraphicsTest();
            }
        });
    }

    public class Painter extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
        private final Color purple = new Color(255,0,255);
        private final Color brown = new Color(171,100,28);

        private Rectangle dummyRect = new Rectangle(); // Dummy rectangle that shows up when the user attempts to draw a rectangle

        private Set<Shape> shapeSet = new HashSet<Shape>();
        private List<Color> colorList = new ArrayList<Color>();
        private List<Integer> opNumList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // Point used for drawing dummy rectangle
        private Point clickPoint;

        // Initial color
        private Color color = Color.black;

        // int variables that determine the position of various on-screen objects
        private int dragX = 0, dragY = 0, downX = 0, downY = 0, upX = 0, upY = 0;

        public Painter() {
            // Adding colors to the ArrayList
            /*colorList.add(Color.red);
            colorList.add(Color.orange);
            colorList.add(Color.yellow);
            colorList.add(Color.green);
            colorList.add(Color.blue);
            colorList.add(purple);
            colorList.add(brown);
            colorList.add(Color.white);
            colorList.add(Color.black);*/

            // Adding listeners so that the mouse may be used to draw various objects
            addMouseListener(this);
            addMouseMotionListener(this);
        }

        /**
         * Driving method of this program that displays all on-screen components
         **/
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int index = 0;
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2.setColor(color);

            // Displaying the rectangle as it is drawn
            if (dummyRect.width > 0 && dummyRect.height > 0)
                if (cbFillItem.isSelected())
                    g2.fill(dummyRect);
                else
                    g2.draw(dummyRect);
            // Storing the rectangles in the HashSet
            if (downX > upX && downY > upY)
                shapeSet.add(new Rectangle(upX,upY,downX-upX,downY-upY));
            else if (downX > upX && downY < upY)
                shapeSet.add(new Rectangle(upX,downY,downX-upX,upY-downY));
            else if (downX < upX && downY > upY)
                shapeSet.add(new Rectangle(downX,upY,upX-downX,downY-upY));
            else
                shapeSet.add(new Rectangle(downX,downY,upX-downX,upY-downY));

            try {
                for (Shape s : shapeSet) {
                    if (s instanceof Rectangle) {
                        Rectangle r = (Rectangle) s;
                        if (r.width == 0 && r.height == 0)
                            shapeSet.remove(s);
                    }
                }
            } catch (ConcurrentModificationException ex) {}

            // System.out.println("Size: " + shapeSet.size());
            if (!opNumList.isEmpty()) {
                for (Shape s : shapeSet) {
                    //System.out.println("Index: " + index);
                    //System.out.println("Element: " + opNumList.get(index));
                    //System.out.println();
                    switch (opNumList.get(index)) {
                        case  2: g2.setColor(Color.red);    g2.fill(s); break;
                        case  3: g2.setColor(Color.red);    g2.draw(s); break;

                        case  7: g2.setColor(Color.orange); g2.fill(s); break;
                        case  8: g2.setColor(Color.orange); g2.draw(s); break;

                        case 12: g2.setColor(Color.yellow); g2.fill(s); break;
                        case 13: g2.setColor(Color.yellow); g2.draw(s); break;

                        case 17: g2.setColor(Color.green);  g2.fill(s); break;
                        case 18: g2.setColor(Color.green);  g2.draw(s); break;

                        case 22: g2.setColor(Color.blue);   g2.fill(s); break;
                        case 23: g2.setColor(Color.blue);   g2.draw(s); break;

                        case 27: g2.setColor(purple);       g2.fill(s); break;
                        case 28: g2.setColor(purple);       g2.draw(s); break;

                        case 32: g2.setColor(brown);        g2.fill(s); break;
                        case 33: g2.setColor(brown);        g2.draw(s); break;

                        case 37: g2.setColor(Color.white);  g2.fill(s); break;
                        case 38: g2.setColor(Color.white);  g2.draw(s); break;

                        case 42: g2.setColor(Color.black);  g2.fill(s); break;
                        case 43: g2.setColor(Color.black);  g2.draw(s); break;
                        default: return;
                    }
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * MouseListener interface methods
         **/
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ev) {}

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent ev) {}

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent ev) {}

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent ev) {
            clickPoint = new Point(ev.getPoint());
            upX = ev.getX();
            upY = ev.getY();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent ev) {
            upX = ev.getX();
            upY = ev.getY();
            if (color == Color.red) {
                if (cbFillItem.isSelected())
                    opNumList.add(2);
                else
                    opNumList.add(3);
            }

            if (color == Color.orange) {
                if (cbFillItem.isSelected())
                    opNumList.add(7);
                else
                    opNumList.add(8);
            }

            if (color == Color.yellow) {
                if (cbFillItem.isSelected())
                    opNumList.add(12);
                else
                    opNumList.add(13);
            }

            if (color == Color.green) {
                if (cbFillItem.isSelected())
                    opNumList.add(17);
                else
                    opNumList.add(18);
            }

            if (color == Color.blue) {
                if (cbFillItem.isSelected())
                    opNumList.add(22);
                else
                    opNumList.add(23);
            }

            if (color == purple) {
                if (cbFillItem.isSelected())
                    opNumList.add(27);
                else
                    opNumList.add(28);
            }

            if (color == brown) {
                if (cbFillItem.isSelected())
                    opNumList.add(32);
                else
                    opNumList.add(33);
            }

            if (color == Color.white) {
                if (cbFillItem.isSelected())
                    opNumList.add(37);
                else
                    opNumList.add(38);
            }

            if (color == Color.black) {
                if (cbFillItem.isSelected())
                    opNumList.add(42);
                else
                    opNumList.add(43);
            }
            repaint();
        }

        /**
         * MouseMotionListener interface methods
         **/
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent ev) {}

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent ev) {
            dragX = ev.getX();
            dragY = ev.getY();

            int minX = Math.min(ev.getX(), clickPoint.x);
            int minY = Math.min(ev.getY(), clickPoint.y);
            int maxX = Math.max(ev.getX(), clickPoint.x);
            int maxY = Math.max(ev.getY(), clickPoint.y);

            dummyRect.x = minX;
            dummyRect.y = minY;
            dummyRect.width = maxX - minX;
            dummyRect.height = maxY - minY;
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Set for storing rectangles, you can never be sure about the order in which shapes will be rendered as Set don't maintain order of objects inside. Try using List or Map instead.